# Get accurate array of dates from sheet

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with thousands of lines, each starting with a date. So:

```
2019-01-30  
2019-01-30  
2019-02-19  
2019-03-06  
2019-03-06  
...
```

I need to get that column into a javascript array and then perform additional functions thereon. I know there is some issue with date indexing such that Google 2019-01-30 translates to javascript 2019-01-29 and a logger on the code confirms this.
How can I get that entire column into the Google Apps Script javascript (using `dataSheet.getRange().getValues()`) and have that be accurate to what is on the sheet? The only way I know is to individually go through each element of the array and add 1. That feels like a bad way to get around it.
Alternatively, am I better off just leaving it as-is and, when I need to output a date from the javascript to the sheet, add 1 at that point?

Comment: What is the timezone of your spreadsheet and the timezone of your Apps Script project? Please add a [mcve].

Comment: I think this is most likely a timezone issue. Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on?

Comment: It was a timezone issue. The sheet and the script didn't match timezone

Answer (score 0):

Get dates in a flat array

```
function getColumnOne() {
  const startrow=2;
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(startrow,1,sh.getLastRow()-startrow+1,1);
  var dateA=rg.getValues().map(function(r,i){return r[0];});
  return dateA;//returns a flat array
}
```

Comment: That still returns 1 date lower than what the sheet displays.

Comment: What row does you data start on?

Comment: My data starts on row 2

Comment: What is you last row number?

Comment: The number of rows of data is lastrow-startrow+1.